# How to mask an image in a square shape?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I am trying to mask a square shape out of a rectangular image. Those area out of square shape will be painted white. I write code as below.

```
photo_data = imageio.imread('./demo/dog.jpg')
total_rows,total_columns,layer=photo_data.shape
X,Y=np.ogrid[:total_rows,:total_columns]
center_rows=total_rows/2
center_columns=total_columns/2
upper_mask=X-center_rows>500
low_mask=X-center_rows<-500
left_mask=Y-center_columns>500
right_mask=Y-center_columns<-500
final_mask=np.logical_and(upper_mask,low_mask,left_mask,right_mask)
photo_data[final_mask]=0
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.imshow(photo_data)
```

I guess np.logical_and cannot handle array with different number size. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You need `upper_mask | low_mask | left_mask | right_mask` instead of logical and, and done, your code will work, also if you want white surrounding instead of black then in line `photo_data[final_mask]=0` replace `0` with `255`, I posted this solution [as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64607912/941531).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you make things a bit more complicated than you need to. Conceptually, I think that you need to do something along these lines:

```
photo_data = imageio.imread('./demo/dog.jpg')
total_rows,total_columns,layer=photo_data.shape
mask_size = 500
photo_data[total_rows/2-mask_size/2:total_rows/2+mask_size/2,
    total_columns/2-mask_size/2:total_columns/2+mask_size/2,
    :] = 0
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.imshow(photo_data)
```

**EDIT:**

I assume that there are even more elegant ways of performing this, but one way that I personally like is to use numpys elemet wise multiplication to apply the mask:

```
import numpy as np

photo_data = imageio.imread('./demo/dog.jpg')
total_rows,total_columns,layer=photo_data.shape
mask_size = 500

mask = np.zeros(photo_data.shape)
mask[total_rows/2-mask_size/2:total_rows/2+mask_size/2,
    total_columns/2-mask_size/2:total_columns/2+mask_size/2,
    :] = 1
photo_data = photo_data * mask
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.imshow(photo_data)
```

Comment: Thx for your comments. I try to run this line but get below error.
"TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method".
Is this because "total_rows/2" is a float number? But I try to convert it to a integers with int() function but I still receive this error. I really have no clues.

Comment: Besides, what I want to do is to chop a square shape in the center area and make the rest area as black. It seems the code you shared is to make center square area as black.

Comment: Following your advice, I rewrote the code again as below.
 `
photo_data = imageio.imread('./demo/dog.jpg')<br/>
total_rows,total_columns,layer=photo_data.shape<br/>
photo_data[0:half_rows-500,:,:] = 0<br/>
photo_data[half_rows+500:total_rows,:,:]=0<br/>
photo_data[:,0:half_columns-500,:]=0<br/>
photo_data[:,half_columns+500:total_columns,:]=0<br/>
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))<br/>
plt.imshow(photo_data)<br/>
 `
It did work. But how to make it more elegant then?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
np.logical_and(upper_mask,low_mask,left_mask,right_mask)
```

you can use

```
upper_mask & low_mask & left_mask & right_mask
```

but actually you need `OR` for your task, so correct way is to use:

```
upper_mask | low_mask | left_mask | right_mask
```

Then you code works well!

Full corrected code down below:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64591952#main.py)

```
import imageio, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

photo_data = imageio.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb6U1.jpg')
total_rows,total_columns,layer=photo_data.shape
X,Y=np.ogrid[:total_rows,:total_columns]
center_rows=total_rows/2
center_columns=total_columns/2
upper_mask=X-center_rows>100
low_mask=X-center_rows<-100
left_mask=Y-center_columns>100
right_mask=Y-center_columns<-100
final_mask=upper_mask | low_mask | left_mask | right_mask
photo_data[final_mask]=0
plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
plt.imshow(photo_data)
plt.show()
```

Input:

[image: img0]

Output:

[image: img1]

Also if you want white surroundings instead of black then replace

```
photo_data[final_mask]=0
```

with

```
photo_data[final_mask]=255
```